# Appium: 'An attempt to register with the grid was unsuccessful: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:80'

Tags: android, selenium, testing, mobile, appium

I want to set-up Appium with selenium grid. Unfortunately when I try to register node, I get getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:80.

**env**

- macOS Big Sur
- appium version 1.18.2
- nodeJS version 10.15.3

My nodeconfig file is [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imch5.png)

**steps**

- I start android emulator (udid "emulator-5554")
- I run selenium hub (with default port 4444): `java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-4.jar hub`
- I start node with: `appium --nodeconfig nodeconfig-android.json`

It results [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnyJa.png)